# Harvmac, Amstex

Tags: fonts, plain-tex, amstex

I am writing a file with Plain TeX using the `harvmac` macro. I have always used LaTeX until now. Two related questions about `harvmac` Vs. mathematical fonts:

1. I tried adding `\input amstex` to get the "equivalent" of the `amsmath` package for LaTeX. When I did so, I got errors in compiling the calligraphic font. Expressions like `${\cal M}$` were correctly compiled before, and give me error when `\input amstex` is added. How can I have both?
2. How do I get the `\mathbb` and all the other options in the `amsfonts` package?

Thanks

Comment: Please could you post a Minimum Working Example which demonstrates the problem. That makes it easier for people to help you and increases the chances you'll get useful responses. It might help to know why you want to do things this way. That is, plain TeX is not going to be 'equivalent' to LaTeX unless you define all the stuff LaTeX defines. But then you should just use LaTeX...

Comment: BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: If you only need the fonts, you can `\input amssym`, after which with `\Bbb` you get the same as `\mathbb`.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually called `\Cal` (note the capital `C`):

```
\input amstex
%\input harvmac % I don't have it installed, so I commented it out
\documentstyle{amsppt}
\document
$$
\Cal A \Bbb B
$$
\bye
```

I believe that unlike the normal plain TeX `\cal` which changes the `\fam`ily from thereon after, the commands `\Cal` and `\Bbb` take an argument (so, `\Cal{ABC}`).